# Extending the definition of stochastic integral from simple processes

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, product-measure

I am reading stochastic integration from *Brownian Motion And Stochastic Calculus* by Karatzas and Shreve. In the course of extending the definition of the stochastic integral from simple processes to other measurable and adapted processes, they first prove the following lemma:

> Let $X$ be a bounded, measurable, $\{\mathcal{F}_{t}\}$- adapted process. Then there exists a sequence of simple processes $\{X^{(m)}\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ of simple processes such that 
>   \begin{equation}
> \tag1 \sup_{T >0} \lim_{m \to \infty} E\int_{0}^{T}|X^{(m)}_{t}-X_{t}|^2dt=0 
> \end{equation}

From this, they conclude that it is possible to extract a subsequence $\{X^{(m_{k})}\}$ such that the set 
\begin{equation}
\{(t,\omega\} \in [0,\infty) \times\Omega; \lim_{k \to \infty}X^{(m_{k})}_{t}(\omega)=X_{t}(\omega)\}^{c}
\end{equation}
has product measure zero. My question is, how did they arrive at this conclusion? I understand if $(1)$ is satisifed, then for each $T >0$,  $\lim_{m \to \infty} E\int_{0}^{T}|X^{(m)}_{t}-X_{t}|^2dt=0 $ and hence there is a subsequence converging to $X_{t}(\omega)$ for almost every $[0,T] \times \Omega$. But this subsequence need not be the same for every $T$ right? So how do we get a subsequence that converges almsot everywhere on $[0, \infty) \times \Omega$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $n\in \Bbb N$ choose a subsequence $(m_k^n)_k$ in the following way.

For $n=1$ choose a subsequence $(m_k^1)_k$ such that $X_t^{(m_k^1)} (\omega) \to X_t (\omega)$ for almost every $(t,\omega ) \in [0,1] \times \Omega$.

Given the sequence $(m_k^n)_k$ we have that $(1)$ holds for $T=n+1$ and $(m_k^n)_k$. Thus, take $(m_k^{n+1})_k$ as a subsequence from $(m_k^n)_k$ such that $X_t^{(m_k^{n+1})} (\omega) \to X_t (\omega)$ for almost every $(t,\omega ) \in [0,n+1] \times \Omega$.

Now take as final sequence $m_k := m_k^k$, for which 
$$X_t^{(m_k)} (\omega) \to X_t (\omega)$$
holds for almost every $\cup_n [0,n]\times\Omega =[0,\infty) \times \Omega$.

Comment: Nice. In the fifth line, I think you meant $[0,1]$. This proof reminds me that of Helly's selection principle.

Comment: Yes I edited the post. Helly's Selection priciple conveys nothing to me.